# Can't tell what's wrong with a simple swap of list elements

Tags: python

I need to swap elements in a list in certain order, which is given by `per`. I need to start with and swap each subsequent element with '9'.

```
ini_nos = [3, 10, 1, 8, 9, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5]
x = 9
y = 9
per = {
    1: 5,
    5: 2,
    2: 10,
    10: 9,
    9: 1}

for i in range(5):
    ini_nos[ini_nos.index(y)] = per[x]
    ini_nos[ini_nos.index(per[x])] = y
    x = per[x]
```

When I run

```
print(ini_nos[ini_nos.index(y)], "=>", per[x])
print(ini_nos[ini_nos.index(per[x])], "=>>", y)
```

in each loop, it prints the right values, but they are never changed in the `ini_nos` list, except for the first swap.

What am I doing wrong?

The `ini_nos` should look like this after the script finishes:
`ini_nos = [3, 9, 5, 8, 1, 4, 10, 7, 6, 2]`

Comment: It does not, but thank you for linking.

Comment: I want to know, why doesn't mine work, since it's done in the same manner as the one in the link.

Comment: Edit: added target `ini_nos`.

Comment: Shouldn't you then replace `y` with `x` in your loop?

Comment: Initially it looked like this, but I want to swap with '9' every time, so I wanted to leave it constant and the one it's swapping with variable.

Answer (score 1):

this is more memory intensive by speed O(N)

```
print([per[t] if t in per else t for t in ini_nos])
```

a step by step swap, smaller memory but O(N^2)

```
x,y=9,9

for cnt in range(5):
    y=per[y]
    px=ini_nos.index(x)
    py=ini_nos.index(y)
    ini_nos[px],ini_nos[py]=y,x
```

Comment: While this is awesome and actually works, I need to add some code that would calculate a cost of each swap and I'm not sure it would fit in yours.

Comment: This works! Apparently assigning the indices separately is the key.
Would you care to explain how is it O(n^2) though? It should be O(n).

Comment: This is a N-step loop and each index is O(N), so the total is O(N2). You can cache one of the index calls between the iterations to save half of the time, but still O(N2)